# Unable to change elements in a nested ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an `ArrayList<Menu>` in my App, the `Menu` object looks like:

```
public class Menu {
    public int id;
    public String desc;
    public boolean opzionale;
    public int limite;
    public List<Prodotti> prodotti;
}
```

On the user selection i show in my `RecyclerView` `prodotti`. each `Prodotti` on user action can be modified but have to be modified only at the specific position of `ArrayList<Menu>`.

So initially i just show items at the first position of the Array like:

```
List<Menu.Prodotti> listProdotti = listMenu.get(fase).prodotti;
```

`fase` is a dynamic value which specify which items of which Menu has to be shown.

Then in another function i change the value of the `Prodotto` at position like:

```
    Menu.Prodotti prodotto = listProdotti.get(position);
    prodotto.setQta(qtaProdotto + qta);
```

The issue is that after doing so all `prodotti` of `ArrayList<Menu>` at `position` will update it's quantity.

So if in my array i have data like:

```
ArrayList<Menu.Prodotti> prodotti = new ArrayList<>();
prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST1", "1", 0, 0, 1, 0));
prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST2", "2", 0, 0, 1, 0));
prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST3", "3", 0, 0, 1, 0));
prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST4", "4", 0, 0, 1, 0));
prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST5", "5", 0, 0, 1, 0));

ArrayList<Menu> listMenu = new ArrayList<>();
listMenu.add(new Menu(1, "Fase 1", false, 1, prodotti));
listMenu.add(new Menu(2, "Fase 2", false, 1, prodotti));
listMenu.add(new Menu(3, "Fase 3", false, 1, prodotti));
listMenu.add(new Menu(4, "Fase 4", true, 2, prodotti));
```

And i change the `listMenu.get(0).prodotti.get(1).setQta(2)` **ALL** the products in the listMenu at position 1 will be set with Qta 2.

All my logics are in RecyclerView.Adapter.

Comment: You are assigning the same `ArrayList<Menu.Prodotti> prodotti` to all `Menu` in the list. So all of them are referring to the same objects. When you change it in one, the others are also still referring to the same changed object.

Comment: @csalmhof but why does it happen if i actually get the prodotti at specific array position? how can i avoid it?

Comment: All in all you create only 5 objects of `Menu.Prodotti`. Even if your List contains 4 different `Menu` objects, each of these contain the same 5 `Menu.Prodotti`objects. (I'll formulate an answer soon).

Comment: @csalmhof i've just tried to create 4 different ArrayLists for prodotti to set in listMenu but at this point even if the prodotti are get via listMenu.get(position) i get all prodotti...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple sketch what your test-case looks like.

(The outer boxes are the `ArrayList` and the inner boxes are the objects of `Menu` and `Prodotti`)

[image: Sketch of the testcase in question]

So if you change Prodotti 1 from Menu 1, you are also changing Prodotti 1 from Menu 2, because they are referring to the same List and therefore also to the same Prodotti-Object.

Try it with a testcase like this:

```java
  ArrayList<Menu.Prodotti> prodottiList1 = new ArrayList<>();
  prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST1", "1", 0, 0, 1, 0));
  prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST2", "2", 0, 0, 1, 0));
  prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST3", "3", 0, 0, 1, 0));

  ArrayList<Menu.Prodotti> prodottiList2 = new ArrayList<>();
  prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST4", "4", 0, 0, 1, 0));
  prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST5", "5", 0, 0, 1, 0));
  prodotti.add(new Menu.Prodotti("TEST6", "6", 0, 0, 1, 0));


  ArrayList<Menu> listMenu = new ArrayList<>();
  listMenu.add(new Menu(1, "Fase 1", false, 1, prodottiList1));
  listMenu.add(new Menu(2, "Fase 2", false, 1, prodottiList2));
```

Here both `Menu` objects are referring to two different Lists, which are containing different objects.

Here another sketch what the objects in the code above look like :

[image: Sketch of the testcase in answer]

Comment: That's what i was testing but i forgot to refer the new lists in listMenu so i was still adding the same one, anyway great explanation, thank you!